# Why am I receiving this error: 'ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected'

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

So I have this table, each column 'A, B, C' representing the side of a triangle respectively.

```
A | B | C
20 | 20 | 23
20 | 20 | 20
20 | 21 | 22
13 | 14 | 30
```

I want to check whether the value A = B, and if so, display "Isosceles" to the screen.

I cannot for the life of me trouble shoot this issue. Here is my simple query:

```
SELECT * AS 'Isosceles'
FROM TRIANGLES
WHERE TRIANGLES.A = TRIANGLES.B;
```

This seems like the syntax is okay and the alias is wrapped in single quotes. Could anyone take a look and tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This seems like the syntax is okay and the alias is wrapped in single
> quotes. Could anyone take a look and tell me what's wrong?

The single quotes is exactly what's wrong. When you alias something you need to use the same rules you use when naming objects and columns, no quotes to let Oracle treat it as the default upper case or use double quotes to allow you to decide for yourself. Making anything case sensitive should always be carefully considered, it's a lot of effort and it so often gets forgotten about. You don't want to waste hours scratching your head saying 'It ought to be here'.

```
select object_id as 'a' from all_objects where 1=0;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

select object_id as a from all_objects where 1=0;
no rows selected (success)

select object_id as "a" from all_objects where 1=0;
no rows selected (success)
```

Edit- After reconsidering what you might really be after:
Additionally, you can't just alias every column as one thing, that's weird. What you might have meant is to have an additional string like

```
select triangles.*, 'Isosceles' triangle_type
from triangles
WHERE TRIANGLES.A = TRIANGLES.B;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after. Are you essentially naming a new column 'triangle_type' to be displayed in the output of the query? Also, how would you be able to display this query without the actual column data, i.e. only triangle type?

Comment: `*` means every column so where I have `select triangles.*, 'Isosceles' ...` it's saying select every column from the triangles row source (the triangles table here) and also select a column that just has the string 'Isosceles'. If you don't want the columns from the table, don't include the `*`: `select 'Isosceles'...`

Answer (score 2):

Huh, not really; if I understood you correctly, you'd utilize `CASE` (lines #1 - 6 represent sample data; you already have that so query you need begins at line #7):

```
SQL> with test (a, b, c) as
  2    (select 20, 20, 23 from dual union all
  3     select 20, 20, 20 from dual union all
  4     select 20, 21, 22 from dual union all
  5     select 13, 14, 30 from dual
  6    )
  7  select a, b, c,
  8         case when a = b then 'Isosceles'
  9         else 'not isosceles'
 10         end result
 11  from test;

         A          B          C RESULT
---------- ---------- ---------- -------------
        20         20         23 Isosceles
        20         20         20 Isosceles
        20         21         22 not isosceles
        13         14         30 not isosceles

SQL>
```

Comment: Not really what? I'm not creating sample data because I'm querying a table that contains data already. So it seems like the solution would be to utilize 'CASE' and undergo the comparison in that code block?

Comment: "Not really" to your attempt, which is obviously wrong. I'm not complaining about sample data, no problem in typing a few simple rows. Yes, you'd use CASE (my query that begins at line #7).

Comment: Gotcha. It wasn't obviously wrong to me otherwise I wouldn't have came here with a question. Sorry for being a novice, I guess? I'll research CASE which I don't have much experience with just yet. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Nah, that's OK, you did your best, it's just that it can't work that way. You're selecting `*` which means "give me all columns from that table" and then applied alias to all  those values (which is what `as` keyword does, but - it can't contain another string enclosed into single quotes - should have been double quotes).

Comment: So - really, your query can't work as you thought it would.

Answer (score 0):

A decode can also help.

### select a, b, c, decode(a, b, 'Isosceles', 'not isosceles') IS_ISOSCELES
from triangles;

```
A   B   C   IS_ISOSCELES
20  20  23  Isosceles
20  20  20  Isosceles
20  21  22  not isosceles
13  14  30  not isosceles
```